# How to display apps correctly in nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, nemo

How do I get apps inside folders to display correctly in nautilus?

The apps show as Desktop Configuration Files and have no icon, also, when double-clicked, they open up with the text editor. This is only true for folders, with the Desktop Icons extension they display and run as normal. See picture: 
 
[image]

As a workaround I have installed nemo, and this does seem to handle these things properly. All those apps are showing correctly in nemo: 
 
[image]

The only issue that I have with nemo (or any other file manager I've installed) is that It doesn't have the titlebar buttons:
[image]

I have `gnome-tweaks` installed, and I did enable the minimize and maximize option in there. I also, enabled those options in the settings, but to no avail. So, how do I make nautilus to show the icons correctly and actually let me run them on double-click? Or, as a workaround, how do I get the titlebar buttons to show and work on nemo?

Answer (score 0):

Using Gnome cripples .desktop files due to "security" reasons. Nautilus represents Gnome and therefore doesn't allow executing them. See [more information](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/x7v2ku/why_gnome_doesnt_have_desktop_icons_by_default/)